# What is the function to exit the complete program in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I have some function with loop, each iteration it reads input, on "0" it calls function "exit-and-save", in that function it saves some database and after that I need it to exit the program? What is the command for that? If I use return-from... it just returns from function, if I use return - error, if I use quit, it disconnects from slime. I'm new in common lisp...

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call `quit` in a Lisp system
running in Slime?

Comment: It might help to see an example of what you're trying to do. It sounds, roughly, as though you have a problem with the design of the program, where you are having a hard time “detecting the end” condition. This “exit-and-save” function seems unlikely to work well…

Answer (score 0):

```
(loop for i from 0 to 10
    do (progn (format t "~&cycle ~d" i)
          (when (> i 5)
            (return nil))))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I cannot verify that slime disconnects using (quit), at least not using sbcl at Ubuntu.

```
CL-USER> (quit)
; Evaluation aborted on NIL.
CL-USER> 
"still able to input here"
```

But if you got some freakish version of slime you could take advantage of the condition system:

```
(define-condition end-program-condition (simple-error) ())

(defun some-func ()
       (error 'end-program-condition))

(defun main-function ()
  (handler-case (some-func)
     (end-program-condition () "THE END")))


CL-USER> (main-function)
"THE END"
CL-USER> "still can input here"
"still can input here"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your common lisp implementation, but if using sbcl for example, you could call `sb-ext:exit`.

Source: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Exit